# Express routes parameters

Tags: express, parameters, routes

I am trying to create two routes in my express app. One route, without a parameter will give me a list of choices, the other one with a parameter will give me the choice related to the id.

```
router.get('/api/choice', choice_controller.get_choices);
router.get('/api/choice/:id', choice_controller.get_choice);
```

When I go to .../api/choice/?id=1 the api returns the list of choices, and therefore follows the route without the param (/api/choice). How do I make sure that the router does not omit the parameter?

Thanks in advance.

*UPDATE*
It seems that it does not fire the /api/choice/:id route. If I remove the one without the param, it gives a 404 so. Could someone explain to me why /api/choice/?id=1 is not getting picked up by /api/choice/:id?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Basically, your declared routes are documented in the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html).

The second route is resolved by a URL like `/api/choice/hello` where 'hello' is mapped into the `req` object object as:

```
router.get('/api/choice/:id', function (req, res) {
  console.log("choice id is " + req.params.id);
});
```

What you are actually trying is mapping query parameters.

A URL like `/api/choice/?id=1` is resolved by the first router you provided.
Query parameters are easy to get mapped against the request as:

```
router.get('/api/choice', function (req, res) {
  console.log('id: ' + req.query.id);
  //get the whole query as!
  const queryStuff = JSON.stringify(req.query);
  console.log(queryStuff)
});
```