# Passing parameters using React fetch to access Node API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, parameters, get

I have a react project with NODE API backend. I am facing issues with the very basic fetch GET request. When passing parameters through link, it cannot be accessed at the server side.

My react function:

```
 const loadOptions = async (cnt) => {
      const response = await fetch(`${baseurl}/pdt/prev=${prev}&cnt=${cnt}`);
      const resJSON = await response.json();
    };
```

NodeJS express router code:

```
router.get("/pdt/:prev/:cnt", async (req, res) => {
try {
       console.log(req.params.cnt);
       console.log(req.params.prev);
      
      } catch (err) {
        res.json(err.message);
      }
    });
```

The result is :

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: You want `fetch(\`${baseurl}/pdt/${prev}/${cnt}\`)`. See [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express routes parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704593/express-routes-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited React code based on the answers I got above. Thank you @Phil

```
const response = await fetch(`${baseurl}/pdt/${prev}/${cnt}`);
```

It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

another solution from backend

```
 router.get("/pdt", async (req, res) => {
 try {
   console.log(req.query.prev);
   console.log(req.query.cnt);
  
  } catch (err) {
    res.json(err.message);
  }
});
```

and modify request

```
fetch(`${baseurl}/pdt?prev=${prev}&cnt=${cnt}`)
```