# Editing table data in SQLITE3 using node.js

Tags: html, node.js, sqlite, express, ejs

I want to edit the table data in the articles table from an sqlite3 database, the code I am using is:

```
router.get("/author-edit/:id", (req, res, next) => 
{
  res.render("author-edit");
});

router.post("/author-edit/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  let update_data = [req.body.article_title, req.body.article_subtitle, req.body.article_body, id];
  let sqlQuery = `UPDATE articles SET article_title = ?, set ARTICLE_subtitle = ?, SET article_body = ? WHERE article_id = ?`;
  global.db.run(sqlQuery, update_data, 
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      } else {
        res.redirect("author/author-homepage")
      }
    }
  )
});
```

Here's some of the ejs template code for the edit page:

```
    <div class = "container">
    <form action = "author-edit" method = "post">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <div id="articleDesc" class="form-text">Update your Article Below</div>
          <br>
          <label for="article-title" class="form-label">Article Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="article_title" aria-describedby="articleDesc">
        </div>
        .....

    </div>
```

I figured I am most likely not accessing the id of the articles correctly but I can't figure out how to do it after being at it so long, can anyone help me regarding this ? Thankyou

Comment: An `UPDATE` request only has one `SET`.  `UPDATE table SET col1=x, col2=x, col3=x...`.

Comment: Thankyou Tim, that seemed to take the error away, when I post, it even redirects me back to the homepage but the data in the table is not updating,

Comment: is there a way that I can just get the id bit from the route itself ? I am talking about the ':id'  ?

Comment: The `id` for `"/author-edit/:id"` will be in `req.params.id`.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704593/express-routes-parameters

Comment: for some reason, I seem to be doing something wrong then, I did use that but it's not returning the id, I even console.log'd it but it shows nothing. 

I will mention that if I use let's say a specific id like id = 3, the query runs and works as intended.

Comment: Your form is not sending an `id` in the URL.  The `action` attribute needs to be `author-edit/xxx`, for whatever the id is.  And the code you have above is looking for `req.params.author_id`, not `req.params.id`.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't mention that I did change my code already, I am looking for req.params.id, now that I know what it does. When I go to the editpage for the article, I can see in the url above that the id is listed as "author-edit/id = x", x being the id of the article, but req.params.id returns nothing.

Comment: No, not `author-edit/id=x`, just `author-edit/x`.  Just put the ID number after the slash.